# List of Javascript mobile events

Tags: javascript, mobile

Is there a list of mobile-specific Javascript events anywhere?

I know of the [touch events](http://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/):

- touchstart
- touchmove
- touchend
- touchenter
- touchleave
- touchcancel

and the [orientation event](http://www.w3.org/TR/screen-orientation/):

- orientationchange

Are there others?

Comment: Those events aren't "mobile specific"...  They can be emitted by anything.

Comment: @Brad: I meant events you encounter in practice working with mobile, that you don't encounter in a traditional desktop browser.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but here link to [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Touch_events) on touch events.
In short - events:

- touchstart
- touchend
- touchmove
- touchcancel

And orientationchange event is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/orientationchange_event) right now.